# Missing symbols from a dylib

Tags: c++, c, go, cgo

I'm trying to make a C api around a C++ library, so that I can later wrap it in Golang. I started by simply generating a dylib with one function so that I have a reference to look at. Then I made a wrapper around the actual library I wanted to use. When I generated all the symbols from the simple dylib i got this:

```
MacbookMainframe:c hydroflame$ nm -a clib/libxyz.dylib 
0000000000000f90 T _Hello
                 U dyld_stub_binder
```

and I only declared a single function named `Hello`, so far so good

When I did what i thought was equivalent for the actual library, the go wrapper wouldn't compile and the symbols generated where

```
MacbookMainframe:c hydroflame$ nm -a ../luxengine.net/steamc/libsteam.dylib 
                 U _SteamAPI_Init
0000000000000f60 T __Z14SteamCAPI_Initv
                 U dyld_stub_binder
```

The symbol I was expecting was `_SteamCAPI_Init` (with the underscore because apparently `Hello` generated `_Hello` but instead i get something weirdish.

Is my compilation wrong, or is that the normal symbol that should be generated ?

The source files are available here (theres only like 30 important lines):
https://github.com/luxengine/steam
https://github.com/luxengine/steamc

EDIT (for future readers):

my problem at the time of writing was that my header file declaration had the `extern "C" {` but my source file did not, so gcc would mangle the names anyway and cgo wouldn't find it.

```
MacbookMainframe:steamc hydroflame$ nm -a libsteam.dylib 
                 U _SteamAPI_Init
0000000000000f60 T _SteamCAPI_Init
                 U dyld_stub_binder
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, `dyld_stub_binder` is the default generated symbol when you compile C++. You don't need to care about it.

Secondly, `__Z14SteamCAPI_Initv` is actually the right symbol. Since C++ supports overloading, C++ functions are compiled with mangled symbol names, so that the functions name won't clash with each other. For example, you got two functions `void do_something(int a)` and `void do_something(int a, int b)`, if the function names are not mangled, how would the linker resolve symbol names.

Info about C++ name mangling can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling).

Comment: Hm, ok even if i `export "C" ... bool SteamCAPI_Init ... }` ? Because that's what I'm doing, figured it wouldnt mangle names. If yes, any way to not mangle them so the go compiler can retreive the name by just `SteamCAPI_Init` ?

Comment: export "C" is meant for C to know that the function is C++, it does not affect the compilation.

Comment: if you want the symbol to be `SteamCAPI_Init`, you need to create a C wrapper for `__Z14SteamCAPI_Initv`.

Comment: So `SteamAPI_Init` is a C++ function, then i need to make `SteamCAPI_Init`, a wrapper around `SteamCAPI_Init` and then another C wrapper around `SteamCAPI_init`,. surelly im missing something :\ My goal was that `SteamCAPI_Init` was the wrapper

Comment: I just say a possible way if you insist to have non-mangled symbol name. Normally we don't need to care about the that. As long as the function is declared with export "C" in the header, it should be able to be called by both C and C++. Not sure why you want the symbol name not to be mangled though.

Comment: Well I'm trying to have it be called by a Golang program and it doesnt seem to like mangled names, so I'm trying to see my alternatives.

Comment: I see, so probably you need to create a C wrapper then.